# Specify static URL for dynamic content for Adsense reasons

Tags: seo, adsense

I have a page where each user has a dynamic list of items, the items are the ones I want to have ads in relation to, since that is what the user himself is interested in.

So I have the standard

```
<!-- google_ad_section_start -->
```

wrapped around the list, to make google notice it, but my problem is this:

1. The user enters at mydomain.com
2. The user also has a specific page for his list like mydomain.com/user1page

So: If the crawler were to go to mydomain.com it wouldn't see the user specific list, so how do I tell Adsense to display the ads for mydomain.com/user1page when the user is at mydomain.com ?

What I would like to do is have user1 at mydomain.com, (since that is his entry point) but then set an HTML tag or something, to let Adsense know that it's supposed to show ads relating to mydomain.com/user1page because the crawler can go to mydomain.com/user1page to see the page that user1 is seeing at mydomain.com, but if the crawler goes to mydomain.com it would just get a dynamic page, that would be user specific. Any user or robot going to mydomain.com/user1page would see the user1 list.

Comment: I think you have to explain better what you want.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa - thank you for you reply - I tried making it more clear, please let me know if the question is easier to understand, or if I still have some explaining to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your question. I think you're a little bit confused on what google ad-sense does and does not in displaying the ads. First of all, the

```
<!-- google_ad_section_start -->
```

is not important. It is just a (html) comment and you can always delete it without compromising ad-sense to do its work.

The second fact you have to bear in mind is that Google for the most recognizes the interests of the people based on the visited websites, researches done and so on. Obviously this is true for those who are logged in with their Google account so Google can take this data. Thus Google will already do what you want to achieve. For the others, Google will display some standard ads based on the content of the website.

For this persons (and here we came with the core of your question), you can do this trick: based on a cookie (or something like that) that you can set to the user through your website you can put a few keywords, which are related with the user list you mentioned, in your homepage. Obviously these keywords should be placed near the adsense section. I advice you to **not abuse of this trick** because Google does not like webmasters who offer different content to user and to crawler. Infact, Google bot will not see the new keywords section because of the fact that the crawler has no cookie. Any abuse of this trick will be interpreted as [cloacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking) and so you will lose trust in the eyes of Google. In the worst case you'll be banned (blacklisted) from the Google index, so be careful.

I really hope this will help you.

Comment: I most definately had not understood this. I kept wondering why it would only display ads for IT-services and smartphones :)